# Customize a table's cell color when the user is returning to the table

Tags: iphone, ios

I got an easy one for you. I'm trying to keep the default behavior when a user is coming back from a view after selecting a tableviewcell. Typically the cell will remain blue for a moment to show the user where that selected row was, but I forget how to customize that. Lets say for simplistic purposes all my cells are green by default and become red when you select them.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (selected) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
}
```

When the user selects the back button, the cell does not show the user their last selected cell, red in this case. I remember there being a variable I could use to customize that in the controller, but I can't remember what it was. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property and method I was looking for was:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

Thanks for those who replied.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the color of the background cell you can create a new view, set it's background color and assign that to the cells selected background view.

```
UIView *cellSelectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[cellSelectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor someColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:cellSelectedBackgroundCView];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
[bgColorView release];
```